# python: monitor remote directory

Tags: python

I'm currently using `python-inotify` to monitor local directories for changes, and run scripts when they happen.

Now though, I need functionality to monitor a ***remote*** directory for changes. The remote directory will be either a `git` or `svn` repo, on a server I have root ssh access to. I know about git hooks, but they only get run on commit/push/rebase etc, not on generic changes.

Is there an existing python library I might be able to use for this? Or can I just open an ssh connection in Python and then carry on using python-inotify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need file system level access for `inotify` to work. So the easiest way if you have ssh  is to just run the monitor script on the remote system.

You can then use something like [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) to communicate the changes from one system to another over the network.